# SQL select performance top 1 VS select 1

Tags: sql, performance

```
select 1 from someTable where someColumn = #
```

or

```
select top 1 someColumn1 from someTable where someColumn2 = #
```

which one will be faster on a large scale table...
got no indexes at all on that table so that wont work.

thanks.

Comment: What is the function of these queries? Why not `select top (1) 1 from someTable where someColumn2 = #`?

Comment: I second Martin... why do you ask when they are not comparable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First one selects one column with value of literal `1` (a number) and as many rows as there are while second returns all the column but only for the first row.

It is not possible to compare the performance since they are doing different things.

Comment: mainly i would like to know if a record exists on the table where someColumn2 = #... 
and i don't need to do anything with the data. a true or false answer will do.