# ASP.NET Login, Convert.ToInt32();

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a login script and can't get the `Convert.ToInt32()` to work for me.

The error: Error

> *'System.Convert.ToInt32(object)' is a 'method' but is used like a
>   'type'*

snippet:

```
    con.Open();
    string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
    mysql = "SELECT * FROM [Users] UserName='" + tbUser.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand CheckUser = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
    int temp = new Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried `(int32) CheckUser.ExecuteScalar();`??

Comment: Oh look a sql injection attack...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lose the `new` keyword:

`int temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`

You're seeing the warning because you're trying to create an instance of a static method. Normally you create instances of **non-static types**.

Comment: why do u use int32? use int16

Comment: While a `short` would indeed use two fewer bytes the question was regarding the compiler error, not the code's memory usage. We could be here for a while if we were to analyze everything in the question, attempt to plug security holes, re-factor and improve performance!

Answer (score 0):

Change `int temp = new Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`
to `int temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Int32 count = (Int32) CheckUser.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the performance by using `Select 1`  as :

```
con.Open();
string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
mysql = "SELECT 1 FROM [Users] UserName='" + tbUser.Text + "'";
OleDbCommand CheckUser = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar());
```

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns an `object`, so if value matches it will be 1 else 0.

Comment: You lost the column selection, I think you meant `SELECT 1 * FROM`

Comment: no, its correct, if value will be there then it will return 1 else null

Comment: But he is retrieving the value from the first column of the first row of `[Users]`, I assume is is trying to get the User_ID (or whatever the column is called for the person listed in `tbUser.Text`, not just finding if the user exists or not. So the correct query would be `SELECT top 1 User_ID FROM [Users] UserName=@userName`

Comment: And when typing my comment I realized you are doing `select 1` not `select top 1` that is why it would "work" in your method. But you are changing the result, he wants the value from the first column, not finding if the record exists or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966591/sql-select-performance-top-1-vs-select-1

Comment: Yes, to quote the answer from that question `"It is not possible to compare the performance since they are doing different things."` Your query does a different thing, you are detecting if a row exits, the OP wants the value from the first result.

Comment: Check this : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/